# Getting null value of radio button in request.getParameter()

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

`enter code here`Can you please suggest whats going wrong, I dont understand why I am getting a null value for request.getParameter("IDclass") where IDclass is the name attribute of my radio button. Following is the code, please run it and let me know. Appreciate your help.

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Salary_Servlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //DOA data = new DOA();
    //String id = request.getParameter("IDclass").toString();
    //List<PaycheckBean> paylist = data.getpay();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();             
    //Gson gson = new Gson();
    //out.println(gson.toJson(paylist));
    out.print(request.getParameter("IDClass"));
}
```

}

and my JSP is below

```
<div id="div1" class="right_side">
    Hello World
</div>  

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#getdata').click(function(){
        var username = $('uname').val();
        var password = $('pword').val();
        console.log("Wekcome");
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/Practice_App/Login_Servlet',
            async : 'true',
            data : {username : name, password : password},
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'JSON',
            success : function(data) {
                var table = document.createElement("table");

                for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++){
                    var tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
                    var EmployeeID = document.createElement("td");
                    var radiospace = document.createElement("input");
                    radiospace.setAttribute("type", "radio");
                    radiospace.setAttribute("name", "IDclass")
                    radiospace.setAttribute("value", j);
                    var Name = document.createElement("td");
                    var Phonenumber = document.createElement("td");

                    EmployeeID.innerHTML = data[j].EmployeeID;
                    Name.innerHTML = data[j].Name;
                    Phonenumber.innerHTML = data[j].Phonenumber;
                    radiospace.innerHTML = "Hello";

                    tableRow.appendChild(EmployeeID);
                    tableRow.appendChild(Name);
                    tableRow.appendChild(Phonenumber);
                    tableRow.appendChild(radiospace);

                    table.appendChild(tableRow);

                }
                document.getElementById("tableDiv").appendChild(table);

                $('input:radio[name="IDclass"]').change(function(){
                    //var id = $('IDclass').val();
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == i) {
                            // append goes here
                            console.log("You choose "+(i+1));
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "http://localhost:8080/Practice_App/Salary_Servlet",
                                async : 'true',
                                type : 'POST',
                                dataType : 'JSON',
                                success : function(data) {
                                    var table = document.createElement("table");
                                    for(var k=0;k<data.length;k++){
                                        var tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
                                        var ID = document.createElement("td");
                                        var Month = document.createElement("td");
                                        var Salary = document.createElement("td");

                                        ID.innerHTML = data[k].ID;
                                        Month.innerHTML = data[k].Month;
                                        Salary.innerHTML = data[k].Paycheck;

                                        tableRow.appendChild(ID);
                                        tableRow.appendChild(Month);
                                        tableRow.appendChild(Salary);

                                        table.appendChild(tableRow);                                        
                                    }
                                    document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(table); 
                                }
                            });
                        };
                    };                      
                })                      
            },
            error : function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    });
});

$("#IDsearch").keyup(function(){
     var term = $(this).val();
     if(term != ""){
         $("#tableDiv tr").hide();
         $("#tableDiv td").filter(function(){
             return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term)>-1;  
             }).parent("tr").show();
     }
     else
         {
         $("#tableDiv table>tr").show();
         }

  }); 
</script>
```

`enter code here`

Comment: Apologies but I am new to web development and programming world

Comment: Try debugging this by looking at what parameters are passed to the server. In Chrome you can press F12, run your code, then click on the relevant request in the Network tab and it will show you all the data passed to the server.

Comment: you aren't sending any data in ajax for radio change is why. No query string or `data` option. Need one of them in order for server to receive params

Comment: I tried debugging it using F12 (inspect element) and I get null at response tab, and in console it says  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: I modified my code as follow:
var id = $('IDclass').val();
$.ajax({
url:"http://localhost:8080/Practice_App/Salary_Servlet",
async : 'true',         data: id,         type : 'POST',         dataType : 'JSON',         success : function(data) {...
but still getting null response.

Comment: You have a button named `getdata`, right? When you click on this button, you send your data to servlet, right?

Comment: So here is the thing I have two servlets, one sends data of employees when the submit button is clicked (Note: I have not created a form) and the second servlet sends data of the paycheck when the corresponding radio buttons to employee ID is clicked. So issue when radio button is clicked, I dont get the parameter of it in my servlet

Comment: Ok I got the solution I changed my method from POST to GET, and got the result. Thanks you all...